# Как запустить заданный класс в JAR-файле?

Tags: java, классы, jar, main

В JAR-файле (`Test.jar`) есть несколько классов с методом main (`Class1`, `Class2`).

Как запустить заданный класс из консоли?

```
java -jar Test.jar Class1
java -jar Test.jar Class2
```

Comment: Каким образом запускается jar? Консольное приложение с командной строки/Java Web Start/апплет?

Comment: консоль   java -jar  Test.jar  Class1.  java -jar  Test.jar  Class2

Answer (score 9):

При запуске можно указать любой исполняемый класс. Для того, чтобы был доступен класс из заданного JAR, нужно добавить его в classpath:

```
java -cp Test.jar Class1
```

Если в манифесте JAR прописан параметр Main-Class

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Class1
```

, то указанный класс будет запускаться при запуске исполняемого JAR:

```
java -jar Test.jar
```

Ссылки:

- [JAR file manifest specificaiton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Manifest_Specification)
- [How to run a class from Jar which is not the Main-Class in its Manifest file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474666/how-to-run-a-class-from-jar-which-is-not-the-main-class-in-its-manifest-file)
- [Java Tutorial: Setting an Application Entry Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)